# find unique timestamps per day

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a list (i.e. my_list) of 10000 elements. Each element is a dataframe that has 4 columns (namely: id, eventTime, name, value). I would like to iterate through the list of dataframes and find for every dataframe the amount of 'eventTime' per day. This is what I have so far.

```
values_per_day = []
for aa in my_list:
   find_values = my_list.eventTime.unique()
   values_per_day.append(find_values)
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'eventTime'
```

Comment: Read the error: `my_list` is a list and has no attribute `evenTime` . Maybe you want to reference another variable, apparently a data frame instead ?

Comment: Didn't you want to do `aa.eventTime.unique()` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the variable `aa` and not the `my_list`:

```
find_values = aa.eventTime.unique()
```

Comment: how would I iterate and index each dataframe by its eventTime column? How would I use the set_index method?